# How to iterate over JSON objects within a hierarchy?

Tags: json, rust, serde-json

I want to print the `name` of each contact in the object deep down the hierarchy. The contact object may not have the exact same number of fields every time to make a suitable structure. How can I achieve this?

```
extern crate serde_json;

use serde_json::{Error, Value};
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn untyped_example() -> Result<(), Error> {
    // Some JSON input data as a &str. Maybe this comes from the user.
    let data = r#"{
      "name":"John Doe",
      "age":43,
      "phones":[
        "+44 1234567",
        "+44 2345678"
      ],
      "contact":{
        "name":"Stefan",
        "age":23,
        "optionalfield":"dummy field",
        "phones":[
          "12123",
          "345346"
        ],
        "contact":{
          "name":"James",
          "age":34,
          "phones":[
            "23425",
            "98734"
          ]
        }
      }
    }"#;

    let mut d: HashMap<String, Value> = serde_json::from_str(&data)?;
    for (str, val) in d {
        println!("{}", str);
        if str == "contact" {
            d = serde_json::from_value(val)?;
        }
    }

    Ok(())
}

fn main() {
    untyped_example().unwrap();
}
```

I am very new to Rust and basically coming from a JavaScript background.

Comment: To be clear, your *contacts* have contacts of their own? "James" is a contact of "Stefan", and "Stefan" is a contact of "John Doe"?

Answer (score 2):

Giving a read through the serde_json::value::Value enum I found  what you were exactly looking for:

```
extern crate serde_json;
use serde_json::{Value};

fn main() {
    let data = r#"{
      "name":"John Doe",
      "age":43,
      "phones":[
        "+44 1234567",
        "+44 2345678"
      ],
      "contact":{
        "name":"Stefan",
        "age":23,
        "optionalfield":"dummy field",
        "phones":[
          "12123",
          "345346"
        ],
        "contact":{
          "name":"James",
          "age":34,
          "phones":[
            "23425",
            "98734"
          ]
        }
      }
    }"#;
    let data: Value = serde_json::from_str(data).unwrap();
    read_value(&data, "name");
}

fn read_value(value: &Value,  search_word: &str) {
    for val in value.as_object().unwrap(){
        let (key, v) = val;
        if key == "name" {
            println!("> name: {}",v);
        }
        if v.is_object() { // if it is an object, check recursively
            read_value(&v, search_word);
        }
    }
}
```

It could have be done in a non recursive way but it was the simpler form I could think off. Besides I think a recursive implementation looks way more elegant and shorter code-wise for this kind of task.

Answer (score 1):

> may not have the exact same number of fields every time to make a
>   suitable structure

It's unclear why you think this:

```
extern crate serde_json; // 1.0.24
#[macro_use]
extern crate serde_derive; // 1.0.70;

use serde_json::Error;

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct Contact {
    name: String,
    contact: Option<Box<Contact>>,
}

impl Contact {
    fn print_names(&self) {
        println!("{}", self.name);

        let mut current = self;

        while let Some(ref c) = current.contact {
            println!("{}", c.name);

            current = &c;
        }
    }
}

fn main() -> Result<(), Error> {
    let data = r#"{
      "name":"John Doe",
      "contact":{
        "name":"Stefan",
        "contact":{
          "name":"James"
        }
      }
    }"#;

    let person: Contact = serde_json::from_str(data)?;
    person.print_names();

    Ok(())
}
```

I've removed the extra fields from the JSON to have a smaller example but nothing changes if they are present.

See also:

- [Learning Rust With Entirely Too Many Linked Lists](http://cglab.ca/~abeinges/blah/too-many-lists/book/)
- [Why are recursive struct types illegal in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25296195/155423)
- [Rust & Serde JSON deserialization examples?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33251881/155423)